# Overwrite folder with Xcopy

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a backup folder that i should copy it weekly , so i use a batch file in the task sheduler of Windows contains this line

```
xcopy /s "C:\backupMai" "\\myserver\backup$\logFile\c022456"
```

but when the next week come the script doesn't run and always show this message :
Overwrite \myserver\backup$\logFile\c022456\MFU1.dat (Yes/No/All)?

I want to overwrite the whole contains of folder
what i should be add to my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I want to overwrite the entire contents of the folder, what should I add to my code?

You may want to try adding the `/Y` option:

```
xcopy /s /y "C:\backupMai" "\\myserver\backup$\logFile\c022456"
```

As noted in this [SS64 page on `XCOPY`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html), the `/Y` option suppresses the prompt to confirm overwriting a file.

Comment: Thanks it's work

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to hear it was a success. =)